# About Gap between two adjacent <div>

Tags: html

I have created two `div`. But when I refresh the page i found gap between the two div. I made sure that margin top of both are `0px`. But there is no change. Now I want to reduce the gap between two `div`.

Comment: Make sure at least the upper `div` also has `margin-bottom: 0;`.

Comment: Please provide some sample code.

Comment: <div class"content">
<p>This is New File</p>
</div>

<div class"content">
<p>This is New File</p>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS, at the top, add 
`* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}`
Simply removes all padding and margins, which by default are set at 5px.

Comment: Haha, funny suggestion. Assuming there is already a layout around those two divs, how will your brute force method perform? :)

Comment: @ connexo Brute force WORKS.. lol. But there is no comment about a layout around it. Simple method that works, and he should look into a reset.css file.